# Texture does not show on one geometry, but shows on other

Tags: three.js

I want to put a texture on an object I load via STLLoader. That however does not work and the object remains totally black. If I change the geometry fora  cube all works well and I cannot find what I am doing wrong for the other object. I have set all UVs to map the texture with values between 0-1 and I can see the STL loaded geometry correctly if I e.g. put `{color: 0xffff00}` instead of `{map: this.objs[i].texture }` for the material.
The code that does not show the texture but shows a dark geometry is:

```
var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 70, 70, 70 );
res = new THREE.Mesh(this.objs[0].mesh.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: this.objs[i].texture } ));

res.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
res.geometry.computeFaceNormals ();
res.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
res.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
res.material.needsUpdate=true;

scene.add(res);
render();
```

The following code in which only the used geometry is changed works fine with applying the texture to a cube.

```
var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 70, 70, 70 );
res = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: this.objs[i].texture } ));

res.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
res.geometry.computeFaceNormals ();
res.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
res.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
res.material.needsUpdate=true;

scene.add(res);
render();
```

So it must be sth about the combination of texture and geometry since texture works fine on the cube and geometry works nicely with colors. Anybody an idea?

Update 13th September: As I am investing this further I noticed that if I do the texturing directly upon loading the STL it works. So I thought I must be changing the geometry in between somehow. Thus made a clone of the geometry upon loading and stored it to use it later. Didn't work with the clone at the later stage - black again - though I definitely did not touch the clone. So I tried using the clone of the geometry for which it had worked directly when loading the geometry and doing the cloning. And for the clone of the geometry I get the same result directly after cloning - black. Gets weirder and weirder... Hope sb has an idea since I am running out of

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found that cloning does not clone bounding boxes and that was the reason the cloned part didn't work. With recomputation of bounding boxes it works

In the end geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true; was the missing piece why the texture did not load.